# Is there anyway to UNION a row count to the number of records returned as its own row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

Is there any other way to bring the rowcount in without having to do a union and specify all of the other columns?

For instance, say I created `#faketable` with 4 columns, `A, B, C, D` and then I do this:

```
select * from #faketable
union
select COUNT(*) from #faketable
```

this won’t work because I don’t have the same number of columns.

What I’m trying to avoid doing is this:

```
select * from #faketable
union
select COUNT(*), null, null, null from #faketable
```

The row count cannot be appended as a column, it must be it's own row. Any ideas?

In this example, inputting three NULLS are fine, but what if I have 100 columns. It's impossible to continually add a null for each column. I'm trying to avoid having to specify a null for each column.

Comment: Is there some reason you couldn't just return 2 result sets, one with the data and one as the count?

Comment: Have you tried a `JOIN`?

Comment: @MartyMcVry, won't that just give me an additional column as opposed to a row?

Comment: @Becuzz, the resultset has to come from one ouptput

Comment: It is unclear from your question if you expect the final row of the table with the count to just have 1 column or have 4 columns but only 1 has data. To do what you are describing, you are going to have to have 4 columns because all rows in the result set need the same number of columns.

Comment: What is so bad about the query you are trying to avoid?  Also, if you are returning the query results to application code such as .net, coldfusion, etc, it's very simple to get the record count with that code.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

I think what you want is

```
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.C, Table1.D, COUNT(*)
FROM #faketable as Table1
```

my syntax is probably messed up a little bit,  but you don't need a union at all for this.

**what I thought you were trying to do**

if I understand the question right, I think that you want to do this instead

```
SELECT * FROM #faketable
UNION
SELECT COUNT(A),COUNT(B),COUNT(C), COUNT(D) FROM #faketable
```

if you are doing this for reporting purposes I suggest using a reporting software,  this type of thing is not what SQL SERVER is for.

Answer (score 0):

After you run a query, the system variable [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will have the number of rows that were selected.  So you could do something like this.

```
select * from faketable
union
select @@ROWCOUNT, null, null, null
```

However that doesn't force the RowCount to be in the last row.

You can use a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do this easily.  You could also do a big subquery, but I like CTE's better.  Basically with this solution, I added a SortOrder column to force the row count to be at the end, and then just didn't include that column in the results.

```
;with myCTE as
(
  select 1 as SortOrder, A, B, C, D from faketable
  union
  select 2 as SortOrder, @@ROWCOUNT, null, null, null
)
select datatype, A, B, C, D
from myCTE
order by SortOrder
GO
```

You can see both queries in action on <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/238e7/6)</kbd>. If you do some research you might find a better way to accomplish the sort order of two UNION queries, but this will get you going.

Comment: This doesn't solve the having to union by adding all of the "nulls" for each column. What if my result set is 100 columns?

Comment: @user2587725 all the rows in the result set need to have the same number of columns. What do you expect to be in those other columns?

Comment: Adam, I expect nulls to be in those columns as well, I suppose I'm looking for a quicker way to append nulls to all the columns following the row count as opposed to having to specify each as a null. Again, if I have over 100 columns it would look messy